# What is the LINQ query to get a Cartesian Product even when one set is EMPTY?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, left-join, cartesian-product

Imagine I have 2 list and one is empty:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>(){ "Ali","wall-e","Ellie" };
List<string> bar = new List<string>();
```

And I obtain the Cartesian Product of 2:

```
var q = from f in foo
    from b in bar
    select new {f,b};
```

As bar is empty LINQ returns an empty result set.

**Question**:
How can I write the above query so that I can receive this result set:

```
Ali,NULL

Wall-e,NULL

Ellie,NULL
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this the Cartesian product, but I understand what you want.

Comment: @ColonelPanic You're right, the true Cartesian product is empty if one "factor" set is empty.

Comment: I agree but I could not come up with better way of asking the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
var q = from f in foo.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from b in bar.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {f,b};
```

Comment: Also we can specify, DefaultIfEmpty("<Default Value to be Displayed>") by using another overload.

Comment: @SivaGopal Sure, an example being `.DefaultIfEmpty("NULL")`. When specifying nothing, we get the default value `null` (null reference) for `string`.

Comment: Why do `foo.DefaultIfEmpty()` and `foo.DefaultIfEmpty(null)` work fine in a `from` clause, but `foo.Any() ? foo : null` throws an `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: @Ruben9922 It seems to be because the `null` after your colon is not an instance of a collection containing one member, the member being `null`. Instead, it is a missing collection, so that gives the exception. You could use something like `foo.Any() ? foo : new List<string> { null, }`. If `foo` has members, then it is enumerated twice (but that is not really a problem when it is just an in-memory .NET collection; still, with a compile-time `List<>`, I would personally write `foo.Count != 0` (the `.Count` property is costless to get) instead of `foo.Any()`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Ah yeah, I must have missed that when looking at the docs.